# How to reference the canvas-rotation by using ID

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

in kivy-language, I would like to change the angle value of the canvas every time when a slider changes its value by `on_touch_move`.

I have tried to give the "Rotation Operation" in the PushMatrix an ID by using "group"

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

kv = '''
<Seesaw>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Widget:
        id: canvas_widget
        size_hint_x: 0.85
        canvas.before:                 
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:         
                group: 'a'  
                #angle: 0              
                axis: 0, 0, 1
                origin: 300, 300
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: (0, 0, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: 100,300
                size: 400,20
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix

    Slider:
        size_hint_x: 0.15
        id: slider1
        min: -60
        max: 60
        orientation: 'vertical'     
        on_touch_move: canvas_widget.a.angle = 45, root.printer()   


'''
Builder.load_string(kv) 


class Seesaw(BoxLayout):

    def printer(self):
        print('Slider value changed to: ', self.ids.slider1.value)


class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        seesaw = Seesaw()
        return seesaw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleApp().run()
```

I can't access the angle of the `PushMatrix` by using `on_touch_move` of the `Slider` in kv-language.

Does anybody got an idea how to give the PushMatrix an ID and how to access the Rotation operation?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a new attribute, `angle` to instantiated object, `Widget:`
- Assign new attribute to angle, `angle: self.angle`
- Replace `canvas_widget.a.angle = 45` with `canvas_widget.angle = 45`

## Snippets

```
<Seesaw>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Widget:
        id: canvas_widget
        angle: 0    # new attribute
        size_hint_x: 0.85
        canvas.before:                 
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:         
                angle: self.angle    # Assignment             
                axis: 0, 0, 1
                origin: 300, 300
        ...

    Slider:
        ...

        on_touch_move: 
            root.printer()   
            canvas_widget.angle = 45
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. It works perfect and I don't need to add anything on the python side, just perfect.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)